# How to switch panels in 'card' layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm new at Extjs and I'm trying to find a way to switch between panels according to user click.

when user click on Button 1, panel 1 should appear

when user click on Item 1, panel 2 should appear

when user click on Item 2, panel 3 should appear

can't get it work. I'm not sure how to use 'setActiveItem' and make the panels switch correctly

Comment: Your code seems to be more or less correct. What exactly is not working? Do you get parentPanel and layout variables?

Comment: when i click on Item 1, nothing happens. the 'panel 2' suppose to appear  instead of 'panel 1' . i believe the issue is in the onButtonClick & onMenuItemClick functions but couldn't fix it.

Comment: Add some trace inside your handlers to see if you're getting variable properly

Comment: ok i added  Ext.Msg.alert('test'); inside onMenuItemClick function but didn't work. what i suppose to do ?

Comment: Then your handler is not called. Try to change reference in this.control to '#mi_1' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your control() references as

```
this.control({
   '#mi_1': ...
})
```